# Strings from a list<string> to Checkbox.content - WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

im trying to fill a listbox with checkboxes by using a list,
where each string in the list represent a checkbox.
i tried many things, none show a list of checkboxes. just blank!

XAML:

```
<ListBox Height="200" ItemsSource="{Binding namelist}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

C#:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> MenuContent = new Dictionary<string, int>();
public static List<string> namelist = new List<string>();

// **ctor with FillM() inside**


private void FillM()
        {
            MenuContent.Add("לחם", 5);
            MenuContent.Add("חלב", 5);
            MenuContent.Add("ביצה", 10);
            MenuContent.Add("סלט", 15);
            MenuContent.Add("טוסט", 10);
            MenuContent.Add("בשר", 20);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in MenuContent)
            {
                namelist.Add(item.Key);   
            }

        }
```

**Edit:**

got it:

xaml:

```
        <ListBox Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

C#:

```
public static BindingList<string> namelist { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillM();
            ListBox1.DataContext = namelist;
        }

        private void FillM()
        {
            MenuContent.Add("לחם", 5);
            MenuContent.Add("חלב", 5);
            MenuContent.Add("ביצה", 10);
            MenuContent.Add("סלט", 15);
            MenuContent.Add("טוסט", 10);
            MenuContent.Add("בשר", 20);
            MenuContent.Add("קינוח", 100);

            namelist = new BindingList<string>();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in MenuContent)
            {
                namelist.Add(item.Key);
            }

        }
```

Thanks y'all!!

Comment: What do you want in the listbox? name? IsChecked value?

Comment: Question edited cause of an exception. I tryied it before but it didnt work.. after fighting with an exception i had to change both my list and dictionary defenition from {get; set;} to "=new List<string>();" and the exception is gone, but still not showing any checkbox.

Comment: did you see my update?

Comment: i did, but i managed to work it out eventually! Thank you very much for you time and help! :)

Comment: 1. congrats. 2. if you think it solved it, put it as an answer. 3. have a read [here](http://www.themissingdocs.net/wordpress/?p=465) about why BindingList might not cure cancer (even though it might work in your specific case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't have a property, you have a list, and you need to bind to a property:

Try this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> MenuContent = new Dictionary<string, int>();
// This was changed
public static List<string> namelist { get; set; }

// **ctor with FillM() inside**


private void FillM()
{
        MenuContent.Add("לחם", 5);
        MenuContent.Add("חלב", 5);
        MenuContent.Add("ביצה", 10);
        MenuContent.Add("סלט", 15);
        MenuContent.Add("טוסט", 10);
        MenuContent.Add("בשר", 20);
        MenuContent.Add("קינוח", 100);

    // this is to avoid a null reference when filling
    namelist =  new List<string>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in MenuContent)
    {
        namelist.Add(item.Key);
    }

}
```

my xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding namelist}" />
```

and your result:

[image]

Beteavon ....

---

To rule out your listbox style, i've pasted your xaml. here's the result:

[image]

---

Try this: change your `namelist` property with this:

```
/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="NameList" /> property's name.
/// </summary>
public const string NameListPropertyName = "NameList";

/// <summary>
/// Sets and gets the NameList property.
/// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event.
/// </summary>
public List<string> NameList
{
    get
    {
        return _nameList;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_nameList == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaisePropertyChanging(NameListPropertyName);
        _nameList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(NameListPropertyName);
    }
}
private List<string> _nameList = new List<string>( );
```

In this method change the name to NameList:

```
private void FillM()
{
   ///...

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in MenuContent)
    {

        NameList.Add(item.Key);
    }
}
```

And make sure your  **XAML** points to `NameList` and not `namelist`

Comment: I did exactly that and failed, tried it again now and it still wont show anything. maybe im missing a reference?

Comment: you're not using any mvvm frameworks, are you? if everything compiles, and you just don't see it, i doubt it's a reference. try putting this after you call the `fillM`: `var v2 = namelist.Count;`, and put a breakpoint, to make sure the list has 7 items ...

Comment: thanks for the "count" tip, even tho i checked it (in a different, more complicated way :(  ) and it does have 7 items.. so weird.

Comment: it's either a binding issue which sounds weird (assuming you have the notifypropertychanged imlementation, or dependency, but it works for me as is...). Just to cover all bases, you're not setting the list to a new List<string>() somewhere after by any chance, aren't you? (some time it's the simple mistakes that get us ...)

Comment: nope. tried to initialize it in the ctor of the main window, in the FillM(), and even in an external class but still no go... how come it works on your system but not on mine? could be related? maybe something is wrong

Comment: what you running it on ? what specs/software/hardware? i doubt it's hardware. Mine's running in a general MVVM-Light project. Might be related. You didn't answer the mvvm framework above.

Comment: basically using VS2013Pro, not using MVVM nor INPC.. supposed to be a simple binding, im not looking to get the "isChecked", not yet.. first i just want to -see- the listbox

Comment: ok so after changing List<T> to BindingList<t> and using my listbox style its working!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
```